# Using Font Awesome icon in JQuery datatable button

Tags: jquery, css, button, datatable

Hi i am using DataTable with jquery and I am adding a refresh button. However, when I try to add the Font Awesome sync button to the button, it just displays a blank button.

```
.DataTable({
        dom: "Blfrtip",
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        responsive: true,
        pageLength: 25,
        language: {
          search: "_INPUT_",
          searchPlaceholder: "Search...",
          emptyTable: "No results found.",
          lengthMenu: "Show Results _MENU_",
          paginate: {
            previous: "Previous",
          },
        },
        buttons: [
          {
            text: '<i class="fas fa-sync"></i>',
            action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
              dt.ajax.reload();
            },
          },
        ],
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"></script>
```

**Update**

I was able to find a way around this by adding this style:

```
<style media="all" type="text/css">
  .fa-sync::before { 
    content: "\f021";
    font-size: large;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 0.2rem;
  }
</style>
```

I believe the issue is due to the style being in a ::before selector:

```
.fa-sync::before {
  content: "\f021"; 
}
```

Comment: Your update makes font awesome unnecessary, because you are using the unicode character. The issue, you had is, that you were using the wrong font awesome version in your sript src, because `sync` is not an icon in version 6.2.0 of font awesome. Like I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

`fas fa-sync` is an icon of font awesome version 5.15.4, as you can see [here](https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/sync?s=solid&f=classic). It isn't part of the version 6 collection.

Since you are using 6.2.0 in your script src, you either need to look for an icon, which is included in version 6, like [rotate](https://fontawesome.com/v6/icons/rotate?s=solid&f=classic).

Or you need to change the version of the URL, which you use in your script src, to version 5.